# Nested dictionaries on list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have 2 copies of a dictionary in a list. On start each dictionary is the same and has some keys/values and one key with another dictionary. I want to change the values of this last dictionary so they are different on `list[0]` dictionary and `list[1]` dictionary. The structure is:

```
list = [dictionary{key1:values.., key2:dictionary{key3:values}}, dictionary{key1:values.., key2:dictionary{key3:values}}]
```

I want to change `list[0][key2][key3]` value without affecting `list[1][key2][key3]`

Note that this is a simplification of the original data as the list is already a value inside a 1st dictionary... ( in the code the list is the value of 'predictions')

```
data = {'id': 6, 'data': {'image': '/data/upload/0_egghdRx.jpg'}, 'annotations': [], 'predictions': [{'id': 7, 'result': [{'original_width': 1280, 'original_height': 720, 'image_rotation': 0, 'value': {'x': 37.2, 'y': 31.990521327014218, 'width': 12.266666666666667, 'height': 11.137440758293838, 'rotation': 0, 'rectanglelabels': ['Person']}, 'id': 'KzkuSDEToK', 'from_name': 'label', 'to_name': 'image', 'type': 'rectanglelabels'}]}]}
#list to store dicts
results = []

#Copy dict and change 2 values
result = data['predictions'][0]['result'][0].copy()
result['original_width'] = 100
result['value']['x'] = 100

results.append(result)
print(results)

#Copy dict and change 2 values
result = data['predictions'][0]['result'][0].copy()
result['original_width'] = 200
result['value']['x'] = 200

results.append(result)

print(results)
#Now I try to change the original dictionary
data['predictions'][0]['result'] = results
print('----------------------------END-----------------------')
```

The result of executing this code is (sorry for the ugly output):

```
[{'original_width': 100, 'original_height': 720, 'image_rotation': 0, 'value': {'x': 100, 'y': 31.990521327014218, 'width': 12.266666666666667, 'height': 11.137440758293838, 'rotation': 0, 'rectanglelabels': ['Person']}, 'id': 'KzkuSDEToK', 'from_name': 'label', 'to_name': 'image', 'type': 'rectanglelabels'}]
....................................................
[{'original_width': 100, 'original_height': 720, 'image_rotation': 0, 'value': {'x': 200, 'y': 31.990521327014218, 'width': 12.266666666666667, 'height': 11.137440758293838, 'rotation': 0, 'rectanglelabels': ['Person']}, 'id': 'KzkuSDEToK', 'from_name': 'label', 'to_name': 'image', 'type': 'rectanglelabels'}, {'original_width': 200, 'original_height': 720, 'image_rotation': 0, 'value': {'x': 200, 'y': 31.990521327014218, 'width': 12.266666666666667, 'height': 11.137440758293838, 'rotation': 0, 'rectanglelabels': ['Person']}, 'id': 'KzkuSDEToK', 'from_name': 'label', 'to_name': 'image', 'type': 'rectanglelabels'}]
----------------------------END-----------------------
```

My current approach is to pass the complicated structure to separated dictionaries (result) and then combine them in (results) and pass them to the original dictionary.

Comment: Is your problem that you get a shallow copy? You should use copy.deepcopy() to get a deepcopy of a nested container. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a [`list.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) function that creates a shallow copy of a list. It makes a new list, but then inserts the references to the objects from the original list.

Instead, if you want independent copies, you should create a deep copy:

```
import copy
result = copy.deepcopy(data['predictions'][0]['result'][0])`
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy